# quartz misfire instruction

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm new to quartz in java and I should use it in my web developing project and I want a scheduler which fires every Wednesday on 12 pm. .I found on the internet that I should use Crontrigger with this:

```
CronTrigger trigger=new CronTrigger();  
try {  
   trigger.setCronExpression("30 43 20 ? * WED");  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

now I want to set misfire instructions, which I think is my solution to my purpose, but I couldn't find good instructions.

I have a draw in my website scheduled with this trigger. I want to do something special if a misfire issue happens for example if server is down I want to do it again or something else.

In the internet I found listeners and setmisfireInstruction method but I don't know which one I should use and how.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setMisfireInstruction()` on your `CronTrigger` object.  See [javadoc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/Trigger.html#setMisfireInstruction%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

For quartz api 2.x you can use withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed() function as below. [Api Docs](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/SimpleScheduleBuilder.html#withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())

```
 CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("30 43 20 ? * WED").withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed();
```